# how to read CSV Tab delimiter file that have different tab amounts per row?

Tags: excel, csv

I want to understand the following case.

I have a `CSV` file with tab delimiter and it should be `11` columns by`20` rows. What I mean by that is each row must have `11` cells, and `10` tabs as separator.

When i open the file in Notepad++, i found that there is different row tabs amount, sometimes `1, 2, 4, 9 and 10`. But when I open it in Excel it works correctly.

My question:

How can Excel read it even if there is not an equal tab amount? Is there a special technique or idea?

See below example. I marked the Tabs in first example and the second image is with Excel.

[image]

[image]

Comment: With out seeing data and the code your having problem with not much can be done here.

Comment: thanks for your notes , i just add two images as example.